# ios Core Plot - symbolforScatterPlot not being called

Tags: ios, delegates, core-plot, scatter-plot, uiapplicationdelegate

I have implemented the following function to plot different symbols in scatter plot using Core Plot.

`-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index`

But the function is not being called. I have included the  delegate also. I have also implemented

```
CPTScatterPlot *sc_plot [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init]; 
sc_plot.dataSource = self;
```

Can anyone help me out in this. What is the error in my implementation?

Comment: Datasource is not the same as delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the datasource only implements one of the plot symbol methods. If it implements both `-symbolsForScatterPlot:recordIndexRange:` and `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:`, only the first method will be called.

Look at the plot symbol test in the Mac *CPTTestApp* example app for working sample code.

Comment: Thanks! Actually we need to be very careful with the name of the function - I was using -symbolforScatterPlot:recordIndex:  instead of -symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:

Comment: These are optional methods in the datasource protocol so the compiler won't warn you when they're missing.

Comment: Are there more such methods? I also need to annotate each circle with a different notation such that they do not overlap.

Comment: Sure, `-dataLabelsForPlot:recordIndexRange:` and `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` inherited from `<CPTPlotDataSource>`.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I get to know of such methods?

Comment: The docs are available as downloads with Core Plot or online [here](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html).